# Test automation of web services, web API (soapui)

Tags: testing, soapui, webapi

Perhaps, someone has already encountered the test automation of web services, API, and can tell how to configure and make it in a best simple way. If there is something different, better and more convenient than SOAP UI for this purpose, please also share your experiences and knowledge. Unfortunately, I have no experience in such testing at this point of time.

**What I need**: easy of use, configuration and support. Visualization of the test run process is not needed, it would be awesome to have a good performance and stability instead.

**A web service that I'd like to automate**: product web API. Beck-end is written on C#. The front-end part of the Web API is accessible through swagger. Requests: GET, POST.

**What I would like to automate in the very beginning**: sending parameterized GET / POST requests, receiving the responses, and checking whether the data is still in place and correct.

**More details how to I use the API to retrieve the data (manually)**:

- Open the browser url like http://test-product-api.com/swagger/ui/index#!/Variants/Variants_GetVariant1
- Type a unique id, and the second field - a unique language and press the button to get the data
- The data comes in application/json format - in the web face of API (or application/xml - if the request URL separately loaded in a browser window), which you analyze and check if everything is correct.

In a picture:

[image: Obtaining the data in web API (for one particular option and for one language localization):]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Postman along with newman would suit your need. It is similar to SOAP UI but is very easy to create automated tests with support for environment configurations. They can be easily integrated into CI process. I have used it in the past to automate integration tests with TeamCity.

Some useful links:

http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/03/07/writing-automated-tests-for-apis-using-postman/

http://blog.getpostman.com/2015/09/03/how-to-write-powerful-automated-api-tests-with-postman-newman-and-jenkins/

Comment: Hi @Kalpana, thanks for your suggestion. Could you send me your email (if possible) to ask some concrete things? (my e-mail: corrupt55@gmail.com)What do you think about [Restsharp] (http://restsharp.org/) comparing with Postman?

Comment: RestSharp is a .NET REST client so it would require the testers to know .NET to create the test cases. On the other hand, Postman is a chrome plugin and can be used by anyone to create tests. I have been able to create integration tests for a Web API project within an hour. Give it a go and see which suits your needs better.